# Java rule engine for Android

Tags: java, android, rule-engine, expert-system

I'm trying to develop an Android app which will diagnosis dog diseases. I already have the knowledge base which is composed by 60 rules that can diagnose 15 diseases, the smallest rule have about 10 conditions.

I searched about how to solve this problem, and I think using a rule engine that works with backward chaining is the way to go. The problem is every rule engine, seems to work only if I provide all inputs before fire the rules.

Since it meant to diagnose diseases, I think the approach is, ask a question to the user wait for the answer then validate rules, excluding the rules which doesn't match to the given condition. Then ask for next condtion based on remaining rules.

Example: Rule 1

```
if puppy & male & scratching himself... then disease1
```

The questions go like

```
1:The dog is a puppy?
2:The dog is male?
3:The dog is scratching himself?
```

With which rule engine, can I have this behavior?

Comment: I think it's a valid question. If you Google for a rules engine in Java, you get tons of hits, but most tools don't exist any more or are very old. I can imagine you'd like a starting point from people who have experience with rule based systems in Java.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Drool works well on Android but its limited to Android KitKat 4.4 version. Community is yet to support on later Android Versions following ART.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13629179)

Comment: The question is "which rule based tool". The answer is "Drools". I can remove the link if you want. There's no part in the question that asks for a "how to" or an example, or I would have given it.

Comment: @Christine Do you have any example or tutorial? I read the documentation, and tried to compile the examples, but could not make it work.

Comment: It's been a while since I used Drools, but I did get it to work on Android. I'm currently not in a place where I can access my old code. If I find it, I'll let you know. Drools has a number of components: it has an inference engine, and it has tools to create rules. It's the inference engine you need.

Comment: Thank you, I tried a CDSS example that was with Drools 5.1 and worked, but I'm still trying to find out how to make the inference ask to the user a fact to evaluate the rule. Something like, to evaluate rule 1 I need to know if the dog is puppy or not, but I do not have that information yet, so ask user for that info. then to evaluate the second condition of rule 1 have to know if it is male or female but also do not have this info, so ask to the user. And so on.

Comment: You have to program the UI yourself. There's no automatic popup for asking facts. Drools is not an expert system shell. It's a rule engine that you can embed in your java program.

Comment: We have already invested in drool & didn't find smooth with Android. Though they have android-sdk but its poorly developed

Comment: Why edit a two year old post for no apparent reason?

Answer (score 0):

You need a survey framework or component as your main base, not a rules engine. Optionally, you might need to evaluate one or more rules using a rules engine in order to decide which question or group of questions to load next.

Comment: "diagnose dog diseases" sounds like the classic case for a rule based system.

Comment: I've studied a lot of this theme since I entered my current job , and also tried to use and test some rule engines , as Drools in Mobile environment. Due to memory, APK size and battery constraints ,  adding the problems I came across regarding NoClassDefError by JVM Harmony nature, I ended building myself a rough and primitive forward engine, with just 20k and opensource It at https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1785 Contribution are welcome!